# Remove forward slash and previous characters from string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have various strings in my app, like these:

```
'0//France'
'1//Italy'
'4//Australia'
'1//Asia//Thailand'
'2//EMEA//Greece//Athens'
```

I want to write a common function/regex which takes above string as input (one at a time) and returns following:

```
France
Italy
Australia
Thailand
Athens
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Seems that you need `.split` and grab the last group ... Kinda a basic job that all developer should be capable to do at its own.

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Stack Overflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: let str = your_string;

str.match(/\w+'$/gm); // Result thet you want.

Comment: @CertainPerformance : I did try to solve it before posting the question. I was working with `replace`, but I couldn't generate the exact regex for it. I didn't want to publish half working code, so I didn't post any code for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```js
function replaceSlash(string) {
    string = string.replace(/[0-9].*\/\//, "");
    return string;
}

console.log(replaceSlash('4//Australia'));
console.log(replaceSlash('1//Asia//Thailand'));
console.log(replaceSlash('2//EMEA//Greece//Athens'));
```

Comment: Since you are new on SO, I am willing to give you some credit because your answer is not correct. People tends to just downvote it. It is best to verify the code first before answerring it. Try to do  `replaceSlash('2//EMEA//Greece//Athens')`. It gives `'EMEA//Greece//Athens'` of which is different than what the OP expects.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting the problem, I have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions can easily become cryptic so I'd recommend using basic `String` functions:

```js
const a = '2//EMEA//Greece//Athens';
// Find the last occurrence of `/` and return everything after it.
a.slice(a.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

Comment: Not sure why, considering they behave identically in this case and depending on the target environment browser support will likely become an issue.

Comment: `.slice` and `.substring` does not behave identically! Please lookup what both methods do. Sure both functions have some behavior in common, but there are also differences between them.